# Apps No Longer Download

Tags: ios-appstore, data-transfer

When I click an app to download it, It’ll start spinning and stay like that for a while. Eventually it’ll turn into the little cloud icon. If I click the cloud icon it’ll say the app has been downloaded and will download again at no extra charge. Then it’ll close the window and stay as the cloud icon. Nothing pops up on my home screen while “downloading” or anything like that. 
I’ve tried the following:

- Restarting my phone
- Signing out of iTunes and back in
- Updating phone
- Resetting all settings
- Turning data/ WiFi off & on

Comment: How full is your iPhone storage?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem not long ago, it was because I updated to iOS 11 and I had to agree to new terms and conditions and review my payment method.

Try to GET a new, never downloaded app and wait to see if any messages will appear, I'm sure that a message will come up.

If that happens, after you've reviewed everything, try to download your app.